# Strange Error stopping CCAction

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

just after some quick advice on the error below. I have two sprites on the screen running the same action. When one of the sprites is touched that sprite is sent to a method and the action is stopped.

If I touch the other sprite straight after the first, this should be sent to the same method and the action stopped, but when doing this my game crashes and I get the following error.

CCTextureAtlas originalTarget]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15e743c0

I am using

```
[sprite stopAction:myAction];
```

to stop the actions. If I only have 1 sprite on the screen at a time, then this works fine, but just not together. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint to see where it crashes. Sounds like a CCTextureAtlas is used like a CCAction. Post more related code for more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that the two sprites are running the same action.

```
CCAction *action = //... Some action
[sprite1 runAction:action];
[sprite2 runAction:action];
```

Like that? You should never do that. You need two different actions. You're technically stopping the same action twice, which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Its not quite like that I have a method that runs an action on a sprite that is sent to it. SO I send two sprites to the method at different times and each will run the action.

Comment: Then in another method I will access a sprite and end the action that is running on that particular sprite using the code in my question above